# Method chaining within a javascript closure module

Tags: javascript

Here's a question for js gurus. I'd like to enable method chaining in a js module coded as follows. I'd also like for each method to be able to return an object literal of various values. In the context of how this is coded, how would I enable the function chaining such as method2().method3()

Thanks!

```
var module1Constructor = (function() {

    // methods:

    var init = function() {

        var someValue = 'value';

        method2().method3(); // chained method calls

        return {module1:'iDontKnow',returnedValue1:someValue}; // how to pass value back to enable function chaining?       

    }; // init


    var method2 = function() {

        var someValue = 'value';

        return {module1:'iDontKnow',returnedValue1:someValue}; // how to pass value back to enable function chaining?       

    }; // method2


    var method3 = function() {

        var someValue = 'value';

        return {module1:'iDontKnow',returnedValue1:someValue}; // how to pass value back to enable function chaining?       

    }; // method3


    return function module1Constructor() {

        this.init = init;

    } // return function module1Constructor() {


})(); // module1Constructor 


var module1 = new module1Constructor;

module1.init();
```

Comment: not sure how you expect to chain methods when they return objects. method2 would need to return an object that has a reference to method3

Comment: you may want to add *return this;* however, your code is a bit confusing...

Comment: I'd like for each method to be able to return multiple values, and be chainable so that I can compose code like module1.method1()--maybe something here.method2();

Answer (score 0):

How is method chaining necessary if it isnt accessible by the user?
So you may want to write onto the prototype of a function, making it a regular constructor:

```
function module1Constructor(){
    //...
    }
module1Constructor.prototype={
         test:1,
         a:function(){
           alert(this.test++);
           return this;
          },
         //extended
         b:function(){
            return Object.assign(new module1Constructor(),this,{c:alert});
         }
 };
```

Use like this:

```
test=new module1Constructor().a().a().a().a();
test.a().c();//doesnt work
test.a().b().c();//does work
test.a().b().a();
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this in the closure module as I defined ...

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick you could and return the module1Constructor function. But thats another thing. First you need *prototyping* ( wich is the only proper way to do this), so you need inheritance somehow. If you wrap this into an IIFE to create a closure thats your thing...

Answer (score 0):

The term method chaining is more related to prototypes, in this case, what I see in your comments is you want to access values within functions, that is called closure, which is a way to access a value when a function is invoked outside it's lexical scope. so in your object literal that you are returning, you can do.

```
 var method2 = function() {

    var someValue = 'value';

    return {module1:'iDontKnow',returnedValue1:someValue, method3:method3};

 }
```